# Hide row in view if Content: Edit link field is empty

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have a page view that table format. I have `Content: Edit link` field. I want to hide the row that contains that field empty. The following is a screen shot for `Content: Edit link` settings regarding NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR:

[image]

And I want to hide the rows like in the below screen shot with no edit link:

[image]

**By the way, I hide some of edit links, due to using custom module has a hook implements `hook_node_access` to prevent some users from editing some other user's contents (depending on roles and content ownership)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [views_php](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php)

1. Add `Content: Nid` as a Field in your view and exclude it from display (if you not added it before).
2. Add a Global: PHP filter and include the following snippet:

   ```
   return !node_access('update', node_load($row->nid));
   ```

also another way is using [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) and check you results if user has not access  to that row(result) unset it from output array.

**update part**

As @Aaron mention good note in commentI explain second solution with more details

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_pre_render().
 */
function MODULENAME_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'my_view' && $view->current_display == 'my_display') {
    // View result update logic.
    // e.g.
    // $result = array();
    // foreach ($view->result as $k => $row) {
    //   if (!node_access('update', node_load($view->result[$k]->nid))) {
    //     $result[] = $row;
    //   }
    // }

    // Assuming $result has data as per your logic.
    // Update the pager according to result.
    $view->query->pager->total_items = count($result);
    $view->query->pager->update_page_info();
    // Add results to view.
    $view->result = $result;
  }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my solution, this will work but will break pagination as well as things like "view more" links and empty results text.  Consider a situation in which you have 5 items per page and your view returns 20 items. If the user can't edit any of the first 5 items then he will see an empty page with no results and merely a pager to view the next page. Maybe this is tolerable for you but you should be aware of the problem.

Comment: I'm actually not referring to that bug.  Even with that patch, the problem is that you're deciding what to show/hide *after* the query has been run, which means that, though your query might request the first 5 or 10 or whatever items but your view has no idea of how many of those will actually be shown to the user so you will have an inconsistent number of items on each page, or even no items at all.

Comment: I downvoted because I do not think that a solution that results in buggy results is a good solution.  I think the right solution is to implement `hook_node_access_records` to write the access info for the nodes to the database so that views can work properly.

Comment: For the record -- I'm not talking to myself but zhilevan deleted a few comments.

Comment: @Aaron I got what you mean, tnx for your note , I update my question

Comment: Your update still has the problem of showing an inconsistent number of results (and possibly even no results) per-page.  total_items should not be set to the $result count since $result will only be the results *for this page*, not the total results.  You have no way to know the correct total number of results without processing every single possible result (that is, all results for all pages) which you are not doing and which is not scalable anyway.  You must implement `hook_node_access_records` to store the access info in the database so that it can be filtered at the query level.

Comment: @Aaron I know what you mean you persist that told your solution is better ( maybe it better it handler in views in filter section but in this time it is not exists by default and required patch ).
By the way if you look at the screenshot  you can find that user just need filter data ( are you sure user have paging in  his/her view) !!!

Comment: I think it's possible or even likely that your solution is better for this specific user.  But if others come looking for a solution to this problem I want them to know that your solution has big limitaitons and is a hack, at best, since it breaks other Views functionality.

Comment: @Aaron tnx for your attempt, In this time I have no time to write a solution with  `views_query_alter` , I am sure I can handle it without any patch and just with views altering api.

Comment: Well, you couldn't do it with `views_query_alter` anyway.  And we don't actually know enough about the OP's access rules to write the correct implementations of `hook_node_access_records` (and `hook_node_grants`) for him.  Which is why I didn't write any actual code in my solution.

Comment: `hook_node_access_records` is good solution butttttttttttttttttt  its not achieve this job with out patching `views filter nadler`.
I have no time for discuss with you in this time , maybe in future I write it and update my answer ( I am sure I can handle it with `https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7`

Answer (score 0):

If you really are using `hook_node_access` to prevent users from editing those nodes then there's no good solution.  You could implement some Views hooks to hide the results, but then things like pagination are going to be screwed up since pagination is done at query time and it's impossible to write a query that will honor the results of hook_node_access.

If, on the other hand, you're using `hook_node_access_records` to actually write the node permissions to the database then you can use this Views patch: https://www.drupal.org/node/620392#comment-10222425

The patch will allow you to add a Content Access filter to your view and filter to only show content the user's allowed to edit.